# How to keep users logged in forever with Firebase in ionic 4 app

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I can't find documentation or something for how to make users keep logged in using firebase authentication with `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method!

I was going to use local storage but I found that firebase give a better option for doing this instead of storing user's data on local storage but I can't find out how to do this!

What I have found to be specific is this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged();
```

But I don't know how to implement it with my Service and my Guard!

This my auth service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/observable';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ToastMessagesService } from './toast-messages.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  private user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  private userDetails: firebase.User = null;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private statusMessage: ToastMessagesService
  ) {

    this.user = afAuth.authState;


    this.user.subscribe(
      user => this.userDetails = user || null
    )


  }

  async siginInRegular(username: string, password: string) {
    try {

      // const credentials = this.afAuth.auth.email
      return await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then(
        user => {
          if (user) {
            this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/home');
            this.statusMessage.message(`Welcome ${user.user.email}`);
          }
        },

        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );



    } catch (error) {
      console.dir(error);
    }
  }

  async register(username: string, password: string) {
    try {
      return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then(
        user => {
          this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/profile');
          this.statusMessage.message(`Welcome ${user.user.email}`);
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.dir(error);
    }
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return (this.userDetails != null) ? true : false
  }


}
```

This is my guard code as well:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private navCtrl: NavController
  ) { }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    if (this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true
    }

    this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/login');
    return false;


  }
}
```

Comment: I've been looking for weeks, found nothing. not even in the docs of the firebase.

Comment: did u find out?

Comment: After you get register the angular firebase saves the token on the browser automatically so he is automatic login you just need to route the user to his profile after registration.